# libfreenect simplecv integration?

Tags: kinect

I installed SimpleCV and libfreenect on pcduino (running lbuntu). I separately verified that simpleCV reads my USB webcam well and libfreenect (glview tutorial) gives me depth and rgb correctly, albeit and a pathetic framerate. What I want is to call cam = Kinect() in simplecv but when I do that, I get the warning "You dont seem to have the freenect library installed. This will make it hard to use a kinect". Although this is a warning I get an error if I then do cam.getDepth(), which says "NameError: global name 'freenect' is not defined".

How do I let simplecv know that I've installed libfreenect?